# SSRS: Group by Timestamp Row and Split Values by Source

Tags: reporting-services

Lets say I have a dataset defined in an rdl that has three fields: Timestamp, Source, and Value.

The table for dataset would looks like this:

```
Timestamp | Source | Value
--------------------------
1/1/2015  | ItemA  | 10
1/1/2015  | ItemB  | 5
1/2/2015  | ItemA  | 8
1/2/2015  | ItemB  | 7
```

Would it be possible to take the data from the above dataset and display it in a table broken out like below?

```
Timestamp | ItemA | ItemB
--------------------------
1/1/2015  | 10    | 5
1/2/2015  | 8     | 7
```

I tried doing a row group by Timestamp and Column group by Source but it ends up looking like this instead of the above:

```
Timestamp | ItemA | ItemB
--------------------------
1/1/2015  | 10    | 
          |       | 5
1/2/2015  | 8     | 
          |       | 7
```

Is this possible to do in the rdl or will it require changes to the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Place a Matrix and

1. Create a row group on Timestamp
2. create a column group on Source

Comment: Hey Aftab thanks for the response.  That is what I am currently doing and causes the bottom result where it groups the timestamps together but displays the actual Item values on separate lines whereas I need them on the same line.

Comment: then you should check your row and column grouping.